# How to map from id to string by looking up a property from a different table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

```
public class GebruikerModel
{
    public String Gebruikersnaam { get; set; }
    public String Wachtwoord { get; set; }
    public String FaculteitModelNaam { get; set; }
    public String InstellingModelMNaam { get; set; }

}

public class FaculteitModel
{
    public String Naam { get; set; }
}                                                                                     

public class InstellingModel
{
    public String naam { get; set; }
}
```

A user (Gebruiker) is stored in the database as follows:

```
int id; (PK) 
String name 
int FaculteitId
int InstellingId
```

A faculty (faculteit) and a school (instelling) as follows:

```
int id; (PK) 
String name;
```

Edit: Created the domain models using Linq to SQL.

Obviously, I don't want any IDs in my views. So I'm trying to use automapper:

```
GebruikerModel singleUser = Mapper.Map<Gebruiker, GebruikerModel>(db.Gebruikers.FirstOrDefault());
```

And get the error:(Destination member list)\r\n\r\nUnmapped properties:\r\nFaculteitModelNaam\r\nInstellingModelMNaam\r\n"} AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException

How can I configure automapper to take the Name from faculty and school to map them to my viewmodel?

Comment: Why don't you just **not** use auto mapper? This would be a trivial piece of code to write and would out perform auto mapper easily

Comment: Because I have a ton of different instances with the same problem. So I should write all conversion myself then?

Comment: If you have *a ton of different instances with the same problem* then you have a design issue. But well that's a different problem. Personally I always think if you look at a problem and think "I'll solve that with Auto mapper" you now have two problems and one of them is auto mapper. I'm not a fan (It's slow cumbersome and prone to breakages) so I'll leave this for someone else to help you with, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not clear to me. I am giving an example here that may help you.

**Model1**

```
  public class class1
    {
        public string ID1 { get; set; }
        public string Name1 { get; set; }

    }
```

**Model2**

```
 public class class2
    {
        public int ID2 { get; set; }
        public string Name2 { get; set; }

    }
```

Note that ID1 and ID2 has different data type.  Now if you want map you class2 to class1 your configuration will be like this.

**Your configuration and mapping:**

```
class2 c2 = new class2 { ID2 = 1, Name2 = "Test" };

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<class2, class1>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ID1, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ID2.ToString()))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name1, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name2));

                });


    var data = Mapper.Map<class1>(c2);
```

Or if the property name is 'Name' in both models then your configuration will be.

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<class2, class1>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ID1, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ID2.ToString()));                

            });
```

**Note**: In this case the reverse map will not work by using .Reverse() method you have to create new configuration by reversing the source and destination with proper conversion.